# Python program (Raspberry Pi) to control the opening/closing of a sliding door

Tags: python, loops, events, input, gpio

3x OUTPUTS: CW, CCW and SPEED
5x INPUTS: Manual OPEN (ENT), then 4x reed switches to determine position, end of travel when opening and closing.

I can see that the OUTPUT/hardware and GPIO.setup are working correctly via WEBIOPi. Manually everything works fine.

For now I've been just trying to use the ENT input to trigger a sequence with sleep() delays to at least have some automation, and then tidy up the travel switches later, still no go. The code is worse, before this, this was not any waiting for the ENT/Open switch but some of the sequence would run.

Have no problem controlling outputs via the keyboard, seemed easy at the time, but inputs? Any idea on this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#DOOR Controller 


from __future__ import print_function
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import datetime
import pdb; #pdb.set_trace()

GPIO.setwarnings(False)


# Relay channel definitions via GPIO numbers
CCW = 2
CW = 3
SPEED = 24
S1_TR = 22
S2_BR = 18
S3_TL = 25
S4_BL = 17
ENT = 23


# Initialise GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(CW,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(CCW,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(SPEED,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(S1_TR,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(S2_BR,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(S3_TL,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(S4_BL,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(ENT, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# Relays are active-low
GPIO.output(CCW,True)
GPIO.output(CW,True)
GPIO.output(SPEED,False)

#def signal_handler(sig, frame):
#   GPIO.cleanup()
#   sys.exit(0)

def ENT_CB(ENT):
    if GPIO.input(ENT):
        GPIO.output(CCW, False)
        sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(SPEED, True) #fast
        sleep(5)
        GPIO.output(SPEED, False) #slow
        sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(CCW, True)
        sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(CW, False)
        sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(SPEED, True)
        sleep(5)
        GPIO.output(SPEED, False)
        sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(CW, True)

#pdb.set_trace()
if __name__ == '__main__':

    GPIO.add_event_detect(ENT, GPIO.FALLING,
        callback=ENT_CB, bouncetime=50)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(S1_TR, GPIO.RISING)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(S3_TL, GPIO.RISING)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(S4_BL, GPIO.RISING)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(S2_BR, GPIO.RISING)

    #signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    #signal.pause()
#def loop():
#while True:
#   if GPIO.event_detected(ENT):
#       GPIO.output(CCW, False)
#   sleep(2)
#   #elif GPIO.event_detected(S3_TL):
#   GPIO.output(SPEED, True)
#   sleep(5)
#   GPIO.output(SPEED, False)
#   sleep(2)
#   GPIO.output(CCW, True)
#   sleep(1)
#   GPIO.output(CW, False)
#   sleep(2)
#   GPIO.output(SPEED, True)
#   sleep(5)
#   GPIO.output(SPEED, False)
#   sleep(2)
#   GPIO.output(CW, True)
#
#   elif GPIO.event_detected(S4_BL):
#       GPIO.output(SPEED, False)
#   elif GPIO.event_detected(S2_BR):
#       GPIO.output(CCW, True)
#   sleep(5)
#   GPIO.output(CW, True)
#   if GPIO.event_detected(S4_BL):
#       GPIO.output(SPEED, True)
#   elif GPIO.event_detected(S3_TL):
#       GPIO.output(SPEED, False)
#   elif GPIO.event_detected(S1_TR):
#       GPIO.output(CW, False)


#   else:
#       print("stop")

#   if __name__ == '__main__':
#       setup()

#   try:
#       loop()

#   except KeyboardInterrupt:
#       cprint("Stopped")
```

Answer (score 0):

Further "SCHOOL of GOOGLE" and I found the following solution, it works.
Would have been nice for some smarts but the magnetic reed switches appear to be unreliable, well, perhaps the test magnets are not right. :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#DOOR Controller 


from __future__ import print_function
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import datetime
import pdb; #pdb.set_trace()

GPIO.setwarnings(False)


# Relay channel definitions via GPIO numbers
CCW = 2
CW = 3
SPEED = 24
S1_TR = 22
S2_BR = 18
S3_TL = 25
S4_BL = 17
ENT = 23


# Initialise GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(CW,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(CCW,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(SPEED,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(S1_TR,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(S2_BR,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(S3_TL,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(S4_BL,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(ENT, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# Relays are active-low
GPIO.output(CCW,True)
GPIO.output(CW,True)
GPIO.output(SPEED,False)

def callback_func(ENT):
    while not GPIO.input(ENT):
        GPIO.output(CW, GPIO.LOW)
            sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(SPEED, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(3)
        GPIO.output (SPEED, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(2)
        GPIO.output (CW, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(1)
        GPIO.output (CCW, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(SPEED, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(3)
        GPIO.output (SPEED, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(2)
        GPIO.output (CCW, GPIO.HIGH)

GPIO.add_event_detect(ENT, GPIO.FALLING, callback=callback_func, bouncetime=10)


#def callback_func(S4_BL):
#   while not GPIO.input(S4_BL):
#       GPIO.output(CW, GPIO.LOW)
#       sleep(2)
#       GPIO.output (CW, GPIO.HIGH)

#GPIO.add_event_detect(S4_BL, GPIO.FALLING, callback=callback_func, bouncetime=50)


def main():
    while True:
        #print ("DOOR waiting to OPEN/CLOSE")
            sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```